# Защита от редактирования чужих записей в БД

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите, какие есть способы защиты от редактирования чужих записей в БД.
Есть БД с записями, которые добавляют пользователи. В личном кабинете все записи текущего пользователя выводяться и есть возможность редактирования. Как защититься от того, чтобы можно было отредактировать чужую запись. Нужно как-то сравнить id залогиненного пользователя с id в строке записи.
При редактировании я передаю get параметров id записи. В строке БД также есть и id пользователя, ее создавшего.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сравнивайте id редактирующего и id того, кто добавил, в условии

```
if (id редактирующего == id автора) {
   # тут выполняем редактирование
}
else {
   # пишем что нет доступа
}
```

Тобишь, всё куда проще

```
$id  = abs(intval($_GET['id']));
$id  = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
$sql = mysql_query("select * from записи where id = '{$id}'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

if ($user['id'] == $row['id_author']) {
    # производим редактирование
}
else {
    # пишем что доступ запрещен
}
```

Как то так :)

Comment: Это понятно. А мне id автора передавать get параметром на страницу редактирования? Или можно сразу в скрипте сравнить например id редактирующего с id автора в данной записи прямо из БД?

Comment: Непосредственно в скрипте проверяйте.
У вас же сессии работают?

Comment: Накидайте примерчик, коротенький. плиз

Comment: > Это понятно. А мне id автора передавать get параметром на страницу редактирования?

И прихожу такой я, передаю нужный айдишник и спокойно себе всё редактирую

Comment: @Batyabest берешь id автора поста, и сравниваешь с id редактирующего.

id автора берешь непосредственно из бд, а get параметром ты передаешь только id записи.

Comment: И прихожу такой я, передаю нужный айдишник и спокойно себе всё редактирую - вот это меня и беспокоило. Значит, я правильно делал изначально, передавая только id записи в get. А вот затупил, как авторство подвязать. Спасибо Kohana, подсказал.